# Why Konjunktiv II "würden" is used instead of Passive "worden"?

Tags: verb, subjunctive, passive

In one of the articles on dw.com passive is used in one of the sentences. In the following sentence würden is used where it seems that Passiv is more appropriate

*Der geräumte Bahnhof **werde durchsucht**. Auch umliegende Gebäude **würden** vorsichtshalber **geräumt**.*

Isn't it better to use *Auch umliegende Gebäude vorsichtshalber **geräumt wurden***(were evecuated) or *Auch umliegende Gebäude vorsichtshalber **geräumt worden(have been evacuated)***

How would the sentence using würden be translated and why? *Would be cleared* does not fit the context. Especially present passive was used in the previous sentence

[a link to article](http://www.dw.com/de/terror-alarm-in-br%C3%BCssel-zentralbahnhof-ger%C3%A4umt/a-39268515)

Comment: Not an answer to the main question, just FYI, the sentences proposed by you are correctly formed as  *Auch umliegende Gebäude **wurden** vorsichtshalber **geräumt** (were evecuated)* or *Auch umliegende Gebäude **sind** vorsichtshalber **geräumt worden** (have been evacuated)*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't plain passive but **indirect speech**. Your examples just lack the introduction who is cited.

> [Die Polizei sagte,] der geräumte Bahnhof werde durchsucht.
>
> [Die Polizei sagte,] auch umliegende Gebäude würden vorsichtshalber geräumt.

Indirect speech in German is done with *Konjunktiv I*. And that's what you are seeing here. The first variant ist using the regular *Konjunktiv I* form of *werden*: *er wird* → *er werde*. The second is using *Konjunktiv II* instead of *Konjunktiv I* because the regular *Konjunktiv I* *sie werden* is indistinguishable from *Indikativ*, as commenters and Raketenolli pointed out.

Comment: The missing introduction sentence: _Neben dem mutmaßlichen Attentäter seien keine weiteren Menschen zu Schaden gekommen, teilte die **Sprecherin der Staatsanwaltschaft**, Ine van Dymersch, mit._
Thank you for explanation.

Comment: Das scheint zu stimmen. Ich streiche diesen Satz.

Answer (score 5):

What you're seeing is Konjunktiv I. Whoever, e. g. a news reporter, is saying *"Der geräumte Bahnhof werde durchsucht"* only knows this second hand, e. g. because the city's spokesperson said *"Der geräumte Bahnhof wird durchsucht"*.

The author uses *würden [...] geräumt* in the second sentence because the Konjunktiv I form is *werden [...] geräumt*, which is indistinguishable from Indikativ. This use of Konjunktiv II instead of Konjunktiv I is typical in this case. ("Zudem wird [der Konjunktiv II] als Ersatz für den Konjunktiv I in der indirekten Rede verwendet, wenn die Form des Konjunktivs I mit der Form des Indikativs identisch ist.", [de-Wikipedia: Konjunktiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv))

I'm not sure Konjunktiv I can be translated directly into English while retaining its meaning of indirect speech. See [en-Wikipedia: Subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#English)

Comment: Here, _würde_ is simply the plural. Compare: _Der Bahnhof **werde** ..._ but _Die Bahnhöfe **würden** ..._ and _Das Gebäude **werde** ..._ but _Die Gebäude **würden** ..._

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich No, the 3rd person plural Konjunktiv I of werden is actually werden. The author uses the Konjunktiv II form to distinguish it from Indikativ ("Zudem wird [der Konjunktiv II] als Ersatz für den Konjunktiv I in der indirekten Rede verwendet, wenn die Form des Konjunktivs I mit der Form des Indikativs identisch ist.", [Wikipedia: Konjunktiv](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv))

Comment: @Raketenolli: Ich gebe dir hier Recht, weil auch die meisten Quellen, inkl. Wikipedia, das tun. Allerdings handelt es sich hier um eine Interpretation darüber, ob das **Ergebnis** der Konjunktiv-I-Bildung bereits nach der Ableitung vom Indikativ Präsenz vorliegt (**Der Konjunktiv I lautet _sie werden_.**), oder ob zunächst nur eine Konjunktiv-I-**Form** vorliegt, die dann noch durch die Konjunktiv-II-**Form** ersetzt wird (**Der Konjunktiv I lautet schließlich _sie würden_.**). Die Unterscheidung zwischen **Form** und **Ergebnis** ist entscheidend. Sei's drum ...